# Event Grid GeoDR

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Looking to start using Event Grid (EG) and would like to find out more about how its automatic GeoDR feature works.

When you publish an event to EG you use it's endpoint URL. i.e. https://somename.northeurope-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events

This URL contains the region. So how would event be automatically routed to another region if northeurope failed?

Answer (score 0):

If an entire Azure region goes down, Event Grid will already have all of your event-related infrastructure metadata synced to a paired region. Your new events will begin to flow again with no intervention by you.

Event Grid’s automatic failover has different RPOs and RTOs for your metadata (event subscriptions etc.) and data (events).

For more details, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/geo-disaster-recovery).